How to make an object only instanciable by another object without puting them in the same file in Dart?
I have an object A in file a.dart and an object B in b.dart
because of that, B is in the public API of b.dart
I want A to be the only one to be able is instantiate B.
I can move B into a.dart and rename it _B. This would make A have access to _B and _B would not be in the public API of a.dart.
But B has a lot of dependencies and b.dart is quite a large file.
I would like to keep a.dart and b.dart separated while still allowing only A to instantiate B.
Is there a way to achieve that?
